# How to retrieve latest file from SharePoint to blob using logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-cloud-services

I am getting the everyday one new file in my SharePoint. My file is stored in "Shared Document/Data"

Below is my logic app flow. I used Get Files and I am selecting Document and included Nested items as I am getting new data under "data folder" which is stored in the Shared document.

I used Filter Array to get the last modified file with less than or equal to 5m so I can get the latest file

I am facing two issues,

1. It takes all the files from SharePoint under "Get Files" and the filter array is not working.
2. I have used create blob wrongly

Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Change out your trigger to be when a file is update on SharePoint. That seems to make more sense for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Follow the workaround

You can use the below **Trigger & Connector**

- Sharepoint (`Trigger`) - **When a file is created or modified in a folder**

You can use this connector to select and get the exact Directory to fetch the recent Modified/Created File.

- Azure Blob Storage (`Connector`)- **Create Blob (V2)**
  Use this connector to create a blob.

[image]

#### Result

[image]
[image]

#### Modified file fetched and added in a Blob

[image]

Refer [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5893/transfer-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-with-azure-logic-apps/) for more information

#### Updated Answer

Here is the list of available directories in SharePoint that will be shown in a SharePoint Trigger. You can select according to your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed exactly your steps. However, the flow is keeps on running and not getting the results. Can you advise?

Comment: The flow keeps on running and getting "Successfully checked the trigger" without stopping. It's not copying any files to blob. Can you advise?

Comment: The file which you are getting from `share point` that file content can be `created` in a `blob`.

Comment: I am copying the excel file. Earlier I used to copy all the files by following the same blog you referred me to. Now I need to take only the latest file. What would be the reason?

Comment: `get the last modified file`

Comment: is its a connector? sorry I am stuck with this past two days.

Comment: yeah it is a connector to get the latest file which are created and processed further.

Comment: I don't see this connector under sharepoint.

Comment: Sorry, it is a Trigger Please check [here](https://i.imgur.com/qr6KlXG.png)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. However, I am not able to locate my exact folder in Sharepoint. It shows only the share documents. But, my file is located inside (/Shared Folder/Data). Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243687/discussion-between-delliganeshs-mt-and-sthambi).